# Fast way to find the maximum of a float array in OpenCL

Tags: algorithm, opencl, multicore, max

I'm having trouble with the simple task of finding the maximum of an array in OpenCL.

```
__kernel void ndft(/* lots of stuff*/)
{
    size_t thread_id = get_global_id(0); // thread_id = [0 .. spectrum_size[

    /* MATH MAGIC */

    // Now I have    float spectrum_abs[spectrum_size]    and
    // I want the maximum as well as the index holding the maximum

    barrier();
    // this is the old, sequential code:
    if (*current_max_value < spectrum_abs[i])
    {
        *current_max_value = spectrum_abs[i];
        *current_max_freq = i;
    }
}
```

Now I could add `if (thread_id == 0)` and loop through the entire thing as I would do on a single core system, but since performance *is* a critical issue (otherwise I wouldn't be doing spectrum calculations on a GPU), is there a faster way to do that?

Returning to the CPU at the end of the kernel above is not an option, because the kernel actually continues after that.

Comment: What is the size of your data? What is your workgroup size?

Comment: @ananthonline Size of data is equal to the global work item size and varies around 25k to 40k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a parallel reduction. Split your "large" array into small pieces (a size a single workgroup can effectively process) and compute the min-max in each.

Do this iteratively (involves both host and device code) till you are left with only one set of min/max values.

Note that you might need to write a separate kernel that does this **unless the current work-distribution works for this piece of the kernel** (see my question to you above).

An alternative if your current work distribution is amenable is to find the min max inside of each workgroup and write it to a buffer in global memory (index = local_id). After a barrier(), simply make the kernel running on thread_id == 0 loop across the reduced results and find the max in it. This will not be the optimal solution, but might be one that fits inside your current kernel.

Comment: you can think of this as a "tree" of reductions and see that it takes O(log(n)) time, rather than O(n) for a single thread.  also, there should be support for this in libraries (it's a really common technique).  for example, pyopencl - http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/array.html#module-pyopencl.reduction